# Android accessibility service is restarted while taking adb uiautomator dump

Tags: android-uiautomator, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I have created my custom accessibility service for my project. Once it is enabled it is working well and serving my purpose. I need to take a dump for certain requirement. But when I take a dump using adb uiautomator command, Android system is disabling and re-enabling accessibility service.
I didn't find this behavior documented anywhere. Is there any workaround to stop Android system from disabling service ?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Older versions of Android have a limitation. Only one service can attach to the Accessiblity APIs at a time. For example, if you attempted to turn on TalkBack while your service was on, you would see similarly poor behavior. Either TalkBack would not turn on, or your service would crash.

UIAutomator Heirarchy scanners depend on accessibility services as well as other automated testing features. This is a platform limitation and nothing you can overcome without purchasing a new device/running on a newer OS level. I believe this limitation is gone in Marshmallow, but it might be N or L.

Comment: OK. I tested it on Nougat 7.0. This behavior still exists. Service does get restarted. Moreover, in some physical devices (e.g Moto) service gets disabled but doesn't get enabled automatically. I was wondering if there could be any way to send a dump of the screen from my custom accessibility service itself ?

Comment: Yep. Super easy actually. Just recursively call toString on the node info heirarchy. It's the exact same information.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this issue on Android 9.0 - Any suggestions?

Comment: Support for multiple Accessibility Services has improved, but no, if it's not working there's little you can do.